# What is the structure and dimension of input passed to neural network when training CBOW and SKIP GRAM word embedding

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings

I am confused about input passed to neural network in natural language processing **(NLP)** when training `CBOW` word embedding from scratch.  I read the paper and have some doubts.

In general neural network **(NN)** architecture, it is more clear that each row act's as input to neural network with `d` features. For example in the figure below:

[image]

`X1, X2, X3` is one input, or one row of the data-frame. So here, one data point is of `dimension 3` and data-frame would be like this:

```
X1  X2  X3
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
```

**Is my understanding correct?**

Now coming to `NLP`, **CBOW** architecture: Lets take an example to train **CBOW** word embeddings:

`Sentence1`: **"I like natural processing domain."**

Creating training data from above sentence, **window size=1**

```
Input                      output

(I,natural)                like
(like,processing)          natural
(natural,domain)           processing
(processing)               domain
```

Is the above creation of training data for **CBOW** architecture for **window size=1** correct?

My Questions are below:

How will I pass this training data to neural network for the above figure?

If I represent every word as `one-hot encoded` vector of dimension equal to size of `vocabulary V` as input to neural network, then how should I pass 2 words at the same time of dimesion `2V as input`.

Is this the way to pass the input for first training sample: I just concatanated the two input words:

[image]

Then I train the network to learn word-embeddings using cross entropy loss?

`Is this the right way to pass input?`

`Secondly, the middle layer will give us the word embeddings for 2 input words or the target words??`

Answer (score 1):

Just think of Skip-Gram (with negative sampling) as a simple binary logistic classifier.

The data is a collection of nearby word pairs $(w,c)$ extracted from a large corpus. For each of those $k$ *negative samples* are formed by drawing a context word $c'$ from a *noise distribution*.

The model has two layers of parameters without a non-linear function between them (equivalent to matrix multiplication of layer parameters) and a *sigmoid* function on the output (not softmax). Input and output layers have one node per word and the middle layer has the dimension of embeddings $d$ (e.g. 500).

For each word pair $(w, c)$, feed a one-hot vector representing $w$ and predict 1 at the output node representing $c$ and 0 at each of the negative output nodes $c'$.

Each input word $w$ corresponds to $d$ parameters in the first layer and each context word $c$ has $d$ parameters in the second layer. These are embeddings. Since each word is considered as $w$ or $c$ at different times,  each dictionary word has two $d$-dimensional embeddings (one in each layer), typically only one is used.